# Incorrect formatted.csv file converted from an sqlite db file (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

In my Android app, I am converting the SQLite `.db` file to a `.csv` file and saving on an external storage - this part has gone fine.

However, despite all the data being present, which is 23 columns,and when I put through a sample set of data, the output looked like:

> "column_1_heading","column_2_heading","column_1_data","column_2_data",

where everything is in a single row and surrounded by quotation marks.

What I am after is for it to be in separate rows, without the quotation marks, such as:

> column_1_heading,column_2_heading
>   column_1_data,column_2_data

They do not need to be lined up as columns, just in order in separate rows.

The code that I am using to perform the conversion is strongly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367824/6613600), the code of which is reproduced below:

```
        File dbFile=getDatabasePath("MyDBName.db");
        DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
        if (!exportDir.exists())
        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "csvname.csv");
        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts",null);
            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            while(curCSV.moveToNext())
            {
                //Which column you want to exprort
                String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
            }
            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
        }
        catch(Exception sqlEx)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
        }
```

**Is there a change that needs to be made so that the output .csv file matches the desired output?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is nice and quick and requires a very small change to one line for the original code.

The line:

```
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

just needed to be rewritten as:

```
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, "\r\n");
```

for it work as needed for me.

Some explanation from a bit of research. According to the [CSVWriter documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html):

[`NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER) is as the name suggests, suppresses all quotation marks.

From the [Constant Field Values](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/constant-values.html) page, `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` or even [`DEFAULT_LINE_END`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#DEFAULT_LINE_END) can be used as a default line terminator.

The observed effect of including both of these eliminated all quotation marks and separated each row.