# Method ignored after createNewFile()

Tags: java, android, file, io

I have copied the method from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367270/exporting-sqlite-database-to-csv-file-in-android) and modified a bit to use in my project. I have noticed, that when I call the method createNewFile() , the app ignores the rest of my method. How can i fix this?

```
  public void exportDatabase(){
    try{
        File dbFile=getDatabasePath("Glukozko.db");
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
        if (!exportDir.exists()){
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(exportDir, "meritve.csv");
        file.createNewFile();  //from this point on, the method is ignored
        PrintWriter csvWrite = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        Cursor meritve=db.vrniMeritve();
        if(meritve.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No data availible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            while (meritve.moveToNext()){
                String vrstica=meritve.getString(1)+";"+meritve.getString(2)+";"+meritve.getString(3)+";"+meritve.getString(4)+";"+meritve.getString(5)+";"+meritve.getString(6);
                System.out.println(vrstica);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

I have found the solution.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

I had to put this in the manifset file!

Comment: I'm certain that it throws a `IOException` at that point. But since you just throw it away inside your `catch` you'll never know what happens.

Comment: Also the file is not created

Comment: So, what happens when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: Not only the file is not created but also not the directory. You should check the return value of mkdirs() to begin with and not continue if it fails.

Answer (score 2):

```
file.createNewFile();  //from this point on, the method is ignored
```

It has thrown an exception!

You then proceed to squash the exception ... by catching it and doing nothing in the `catch` block.

If you printed the exception's stacktrace instead of squashing it, you would probably see a big clue about what has caused the exception.  Once you know what causes it you can then figure out how to fix it.

> Also the file is not created

Yup.  The method call failed.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution. I forgot to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to the manifest

Comment: @JernejKalin Still, you should do something meaningful inside your `catch` block