# Android Studio | Java | Convert SQlite Database to CSV and store it on the phone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv, save

I am new to programing and this website.
My sincere apologies if I am doing this wrong.

I found help from Pete [Exporting SQLite Database to csv file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367270/exporting-sqlite-database-to-csv-file-in-android) here but my problem is that I can't call the method in my application.

Here ist Pete's Code.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
* Can export an sqlite databse into a csv file.
*
* The file has on the top dbVersion and on top of each table data the name of the table
*
* Inspired by
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367270/exporting-sqlite-database-to-csv-file-in-android
* and some other SO threads as well.
*
*/
public class SqliteExporter {
   private static final String TAG = SqliteExporter.class.getSimpleName();

   public static final String DB_BACKUP_DB_VERSION_KEY = "dbVersion";
   public static final String DB_BACKUP_TABLE_NAME = "table";

   public static String export(SQLiteDatabase db) throws IOException{
       if( !FileUtils.isExternalStorageWritable() ){
           throw new IOException("Cannot write to external storage");
       }
       File backupDir = FileUtils.createDirIfNotExist(FileUtils.getAppDir() + "/backup");
       String fileName = createBackupFileName();
       File backupFile = new File(backupDir, fileName);
       boolean success = backupFile.createNewFile();
       if(!success){
           throw new IOException("Failed to create the backup file");
       }
       List<String> tables = getTablesOnDataBase(db);
       Log.d(TAG, "Started to fill the backup file in " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath());
       long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       writeCsv(backupFile, db, tables);
       long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d(TAG, "Creating backup took " + (endTime - starTime) + "ms.");

       return backupFile.getAbsolutePath();
   }

   private static String createBackupFileName(){
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm");
       return "db_backup_" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".csv";
   }

   /**
    * Get all the table names we have in db
    *
    * @param db
    * @return
    */
   public static List<String> getTablesOnDataBase(SQLiteDatabase db){
       Cursor c = null;
       List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
       try{
           c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
               while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                   tables.add(c.getString(0));
                   c.moveToNext();
               }
           }
       }
       catch(Exception throwable){
           Log.e(TAG, "Could not get the table names from db", throwable);
       }
       finally{
           if(c!=null)
               c.close();
       }
       return tables;
   }

   private static void writeCsv(File backupFile, SQLiteDatabase db, List<String> tables){
       CSVWriter csvWrite = null;
       Cursor curCSV = null;
       try {
           csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(backupFile));
           writeSingleValue(csvWrite, DB_BACKUP_DB_VERSION_KEY + "=" + db.getVersion());
           for(String table: tables){
               writeSingleValue(csvWrite, DB_BACKUP_TABLE_NAME + "=" + table);
               curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table,null);
               csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
               while(curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                   int columns = curCSV.getColumnCount();
                   String[] columnArr = new String[columns];
                   for( int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
                       columnArr[i] = curCSV.getString(i);
                   }
                   csvWrite.writeNext(columnArr);
               }
           }
       }
       catch(Exception sqlEx) {
           Log.e(TAG, sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
       }finally {
           if(csvWrite != null){
               try {
                   csvWrite.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           if( curCSV != null ){
               curCSV.close();
           }
       }
   }

   private static void writeSingleValue(CSVWriter writer, String value){
       writer.writeNext(new String[]{value});
   }
}
```

```
public class FileUtils {

    public static String getAppDir(){
        return App.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + App.getContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
    }

    public static File createDirIfNotExist(String path){
        File dir = new File(path);
        if( !dir.exists() ){
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        return dir;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }
}
```

"You can call it with SqliteExporter.export(db) where db is the SQLiteDatabase object, which you can get for example from the sqliteOpenHelper with getReadableDatabase()"

**And here is my Attempt to call the method.**

```
    public void share(View view) throws IOException {


        AttackDatabaseHelper myDB = new AttackDatabaseHelper(Statistics.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
        SqliteExporter.export(db);



    }
```

But I keep getting this Error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12727)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12727) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create the backup file
        at com.example.migraineapp.SQLExporter.SqliteExporter.export(SqliteExporter.java:43)
        at com.example.migraineapp.Statistics.datenTeilenButton(Statistics.java:92)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12727) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Thank you for your time and enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might also struggle.

This works now for me.
This is in the Java Class i am trying to call the method.

```
public void share(View view) {
    myDB = new AttackDatabaseHelper(this);
    myDB.readAllData();
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        SqliteExporter.export(db);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this in the FileUtils.java

```
    private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static String getAppDir(){
    //return App.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + App.getContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
    return context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name);


}
```